# using Symfony class loader

Tags: php, symfony

Recently, I'm diving into symfony's class loader component. However, I need to solve an issue.
I have the following folder structure;

```
-> project
    -> public
        -> index.php
    -> package
        -> Request.php
```

In `index.php` I'm using the following statements to load the class loader of Symfony;

```
define ('ROOT', dirname(dirname(__FILE__)));

$paths = array(
    'system' => ROOT . '/package'
);

$namespaces = array(
    'MyNamespace' => $paths['system']
);

require $paths['vendor'] .
    '/symfony/class-loader/Symfony/Component/ClassLoader/UniversalClassLoader.php';

use Symfony\Component\ClassLoader\UniversalClassLoader;

$autoload = new UniversalClassLoader();
$autoload->registerNamespaces($namespaces);
$autoload->register();

use MyNamespace\Request;

Request::create();
```

In `Request.php`, I have the following code;

```
namespace MyNamespace;

class Request
{
    static public function create()
    {

    }
}
```

However, in index.php file, It says that Request class can't be found

So, What am I doing wrong here ? Any ideas ?

Comment: Well.  Before diving into this, is there any particular reason you can't use composer's autoload?  Be glad to show you how.  Even Symfony 2's framework uses composer instead of the UniversalClassLoader.